# embeded youtube video doesn't play on android

Tags: php, youtube

On my website, I'm tryng to display some youtube videos. On the database I have the address on the youtube video and I'm trying to display it on my site. The problem is that this code doesn't work when the website is visited by a tablet.

I have no idea why, and also I don't know how to debug the problem.

```
<?php    
// url of video
$url = $data['video'];

// we get the unique video id from the url by matching the pattern
preg_match("/v=([^&]+)/i", $url, $matches);
$id = $matches[1];

// template for generating embed codes
$code = '<object width="425" height="344"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/{id}&hl=en_US&fs=1&"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/{id}&hl=en_US&fs=1&" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344"></embed></object>';

// replace each {id} with the actual ID of the video to get embed code
$code = str_replace('{id}', $id, $code);

if(isset($id)&& $id !== '') { 
    echo $code; 
} 
?>
```

Can you help me with some pointers?

Comment: `type="application/x-shockwave-flash"`. Flash is useless on mobile devices. very few support it, and even fewer people even have it installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The embed code you're using is the super ancient `<object>` version. Use YouTube's newer `<iframe>`-based embeds instead and it should work on more mobile devices:

```
$code = '<iframe width="425" height="344" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/{id}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```